# Unknown host 'repo.maven.apache.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle. android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i faced this problem in android studio can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are able to access Maven from your browser:

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Try setting proxy in your Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: yes i was able to acces that web site and also the http proxy configuration are like yours

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is a long shot but I was facing this same error because I did not had a run/debug configuration.

If it is your case you will see 'No configuration' instead of what I show you on the following image:

[image: run/debug configuration]

I solved it adding a default android app configuration template:

[image]